# Error al ejecutar un script debido a las extensiones de Python (PIP)

Tags: python, mysql, cmd

verán en el CMD ya estando en la carpeta donde tengo mi programa y con el ambiente virtual activado  quiero ejecutar este comando modellogs.py que es para crear unas tablas en la base de datos que tengo en MySQL pero me salen errores de importación 'Markup' del modulo 'jinja2':

```
(eapsavenv) C:\Users\conta\eapsadbs>python modellogs.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "modellogs.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import db
  File "C:\Users\conta\eapsadbs\app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "C:\Users\conta\eapsadbs\eapsavenv\lib\site-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
ImportError: cannot import name 'Markup' from 'jinja2' (C:\Users\conta\eapsadbs\eapsavenv\lib\site-packages\jinja2\__init__.py)
```

Ya intente reinstalar esa extensión y incluso actualizarla pero no parece funcionar, alguien tiene idea de que podría ser.
Agradezco mucho la atención.

Comment: las instalaste en ese ambiente virtual?

Comment: Así es, todos las extensiones PIP están instaladas en ese ambiente virtual

Comment: **Estas son las extensiones que he usado:**
'Flask==1.0.2'
'Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.0'
'Flask-APScheduler==1.11.0'
'Flask-Mail==0.9.1'
'Flask-Login==0.4.1'
'Flask-WTF==0.14.2' 
'openpyxl==2.6.2'
'wheel==0.33.4'
'beautifulsoup4==4.8.0'
'plotly==4.3.0'
'pandas==0.25.3'
'psutil==5.6.7'
'requests==2.22.0'
'pytz==2019.3'
'werkzeug==0.16.1'
'Jinja2==2.11.3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo resolví, solo cambie las versiones de las extensiones PIP